# Bramble with order 5 for the Wagner graph

Tags: co.combinatorics, graph-theory

For treewidth $3$, there are four forbidden minors: K5, the graph of the octahedron, the pentagonal prism graph, and the Wagner graph.

This implies that the Wagner graph should have tree-width at least $4$ (since it is a minor of itself).

A graph has a bramble of order k if and only if it has treewidth at least $k − 1$. So the Wagner graph should have a bramble of order $5$.

However, I am struggling to construct such a bramble, nor can I find a paper that provides it to my satisfaction. Could someone please draw me a picture, or even provide a textual representation of a bramble with its corresponding hitting set for the Wagner graph? Or else, explain if I've made a mistake in my understanding?

Comment: Let's denote the vertices of the Wagner graph by $0,\dots, 7$ with edges from $i$ to $i+1 \mod 8$ and from $i$ to $i+4 \mod 8$. If i didn't overlook something, then $(0,1), (1,2), \dots, (6,7),(7,0)$ together with $(0,4)$ and $(1,5)$ form a bramble. The only way to hit the first 8 edges with 4 vertices is to take all odd or all even numbers, but then we'd miss at least one of the last two. Hence a minimal hitting set must contain at least 5 vertices.

Comment: Thank you, that works!